# Pytest: create SparkSession

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pytest

I need to test my Spark project using pytest and I dont understand how to create a Spark Session. I did some research and came up with:

```
import pytest
import unittest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def spark_session():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("test").getOrCreate()
    return spark

class Testdb2connection(unittest.TestCase):
    @pytest.mark.usefixtures("spark_session")
    def test_connectdb2(self):
       with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
          return spark_session.format('jdbc')\
          ...
```

However, when running the test, I get:

> 'AttributeError: 'function' Object has no attribute 'format'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [Mixing pytest fixtures into unittest.TestCase subclasses using marks](https://pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/unittest.html#mixing-pytest-fixtures-into-unittest-testcase-subclasses-using-marks), you can define the `spark_session` with scope `class` and add the spark session into `cls` attribute of the request context to be able to use it as attribute in the class using that fixture.

Try with the following modified code:

```
import pytest
import unittest
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def spark_session(request):
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").appName("test").getOrCreate()

    request.addfinalizer(lambda: spark.stop()) # to teardown the session after test

    request.cls.spark = spark


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("spark_session")
class Testdb2connection(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_connectdb2(self):
        assert isinstance(self.spark, SparkSession)
```

Running the test:

```sh
pytest ./mytest.py

.                                        [100%]                                                          
1 passed in 4.12s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I can indeed run the same test successfully with your code, however the one problem with 'AttributeError: 'function' Object has no attribute 'format' remains, when running spark_session.format('jdbc')\

Comment: @Moritz the `spark_session` fixture is now as passed as a class attribute, so you need to use `self.spark.read.format("jdbc")...` not `spark_session.format('jdbc')...`